# trying to replace the index of a string with a character of another string in the corresponding index

Tags: javascript

```
document.onkeyup = function(event){
  if(answer.indexOf(event.key) > -1){
  console.log(answer.indexOf(event.key));
  console.log(typeof event.key);
  //cover[answer.indexOf(event.key)] = event.key; this doesnt work
  //cover.replace(cover[answer.indexOf(event.key)],event.key); this doesnt 
  work
  console.log(cover);
  }
}
```

I have a string that looks like this: "-------" that represents a hidden answer of the same length. When the user hits a key that is in the answer string, I want that character to appear in the hidden string at the same index.

Comment: Can there be more than a single shown character at once (or are you only showing the current letter of the key that was just pressed)?

Comment: its hangman.. the more correct entries, the more of the string will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var answer = 'correcthorsebatterystaple';
// generate an array of '-' the same length as the answer
var cover = answer.split('').map(x => '-');
document.getElementById('c').innerText = cover.join('');

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  var key = e.key;
  for (var i = 0; i < cover.length; i++) {
    // for each instance of the pressed letter in the answer, replace the corresponding dash(es) in cover
    if (answer[i] === key) cover[i] = key;
  }
  document.getElementById('c').innerText = cover.join('');
}
```

```html
<span id="c" style="font-family:monospace"></span>
```

Comment: can you explain the 2nd line. I can understand the purpose of it but if you could break it down that'd be great

Comment: `answer.split('')` splits the string into an array of characters, and `.map(x => '-')` replaces each character in the array with a `-`.